# Cloudinary environment not set in php?

Tags: php, file-upload, cloudinary

its my first time using Cloudinary. I'm trying to upload an image to cloudinary but I'm getting an error that my environment isn't set or not set correctly.

I have no idea why its not being set, I just copied what cloudinary said I had to do.

cloudinary version: `"cloudinary/cloudinary_php": "^2.10"`

this is my code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Cloudinary\Cloudinary;
use Cloudinary\Api\Upload\UploadApi;

$cloudinary = new Cloudinary(
    [
        'cloud' => [
            'cloud_name' => 'XXXXXXX',
            'api_key'    => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
            'api_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        ],
    ]
);

$uploadApi = new UploadApi($cloudinary);

$result = $uploadApi->upload("images/signup-image.jpg", [
  'folder' => 'promptopolis', // Optional: Specify a folder in Cloudinary
]);
  
print_r($result);
```

The full error i'm receiving:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Cloudinary\Exception\ConfigurationException: Invalid configuration, please set up your environment in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\eindwerk\vendor\cloudinary\cloudinary_php\src\Configuration\Configuration.php:179 
> Stack trace: 
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\php\eindwerk\vendor\cloudinary\cloudinary_php\src\Configuration\Configuration.php(138): Cloudinary\Configuration\Configuration->import(Object(Cloudinary\Cloudinary)) 
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\php\eindwerk\vendor\cloudinary\cloudinary_php\src\Configuration\Configuration.php(119): Cloudinary\Configuration\Configuration->init(Object(Cloudinary\Cloudinary), true) 
> #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\php\eindwerk\vendor\cloudinary\cloudinary_php\src\Api\ApiClient.php(88): Cloudinary\Configuration\Configuration->__construct(Object(Cloudinary\Cloudinary)) 
> #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\php\eindwerk\vendor\cloudinary\cloudinary_php\src\Api\ApiClient.php(53): Cloudinary\Api\ApiClient->configuration(Object(Cloudinary\Cloudinary)) 
> #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\php\eindwerk\vendor\cloudinary\cloudinary_php\src\Api\Upload\UploadApi.php(51): Cloudinary\Api\ApiClient->__construct(Object(Cloudinary\Cloudinary)) 
> #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\php\eindwerk\test.php(17): Cloudinary\Api\Upload\UploadApi->__construct(Object(Cloudinary\Cloudinary)) 
> #6 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\eindwerk\vendor\cloudinary\cloudinary_php\src\Configuration\Configuration.php on line 179

Comment: Did you read the SDK Manual yet? [This looks like a good place to start](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_integration#configuration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**

Using this code

```
(new UploadApi())->upload('images/signup-image.jpg');
```

instead of

```
$uploadApi = new UploadApi($cloudinary);

$result = $uploadApi->upload("images/signup-image.jpg", [
  'folder' => 'promptopolis', // Optional: Specify a folder in Cloudinary
]);
```

fixed it for me.